# Using \tag in align environment in \[...\]

Tags: math-mode, align

Is there any way to use `\tag` in side the `\align` environment inside `\[...\]`?

With MathJax, it seems that if you have something like this:

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
x &= 1 \tag{tag}\\
\end{aligned}
\]
```

it is rendered properly. However, putting the same thing in a TeX document and trying to compile it throws errors:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{align}
x &= 1 \tag{tag}\\
\end{align}
\]

\end{document}
```

The two errors I get are "erroneous nesting of equation structures" and "\tag not allowed here."

So essentially my question is: is it possible in any way to use the `\tag` in a `\align` environment inside `\[...\]`?

Comment: `\begin{align*}x&=1\tag{tag}\\y&=2\tag{tug}\end{align*}`?  But please add a MWE.

Comment: In `align`, but not in `aligned`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti It seems like that throws an error for the erroneous nesting of equation structures when compiling as well, although it works in MathJax? Sorry, forgot that wasn't a MWE :)

Comment: @Bernard thanks, but even with `align` it gives the erroneous nesting error.

Comment: `\tag` can _only_ be used in math mode, but only at a level where an equation number would make sense so outside the `aligned`

Comment: @SkeletonBow if you are using `align` then you would not have the outer `\[` i assume you left the `\[` in place which is why you are getting an error but that is unrelated to `\tag`

Comment: I’ve checked it with a compiler, and the code I posted in [my previous comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342562/using-tag-in-align-environment-in-mathmode#comment840581_342562) works as expected.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Ah, sorry. I'm talking about in math mode `\[...\]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, thank you very much. I'm actually talking about doing it *specifically* in math mode, inside the `\[...\]`, which I assume now isn't possible. Well, thank you regardless!

Comment: No why do you say it isn't possible? `\[\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}\tag{foo}\]` should work fine.

Comment: You are mis-using the term "math mode" which is confusing people trying to help you. `aligned` `align` `$` `\[` all  have content in  math mode.

Comment: Wow, that makes sense. Sorry about that. I updated my question accordingly. The problem with your solution is that I can't tag equations inside the `\align` environment individually... unless you suggest that I do something like this?

`\[\begin{aligned} x &= 1 \\ \end{aligned}\tag{foo}\]`
on one line and then 
`$$\begin{aligned} y &= 2 \\ \end{aligned}\tag{bar}$$`

Comment: At this point, I think it could be useful if you added to your question a picture of the output you wish to get; even a photo of a hand-made drawing will do.  I‘m going to sleep, now, but, for sure, someone else will answer… :-)

Comment: a quick google suggests pandoc has/had issues with this eg this issue which is closed but doesn't inspire confidence that it is fixed as most of the discussion is confused about latex syntax https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1938

Comment: the way to tag individual lines is to use `align` as in Gustavo's answer. If pandoc can not create that that should be raised as a pandoc issue and it's basically off topic for this site.  If a tool can not generate correct tex then that isn't really a tex issue.

Comment: Yeah, I know... I raised an issue myself and the developer mentioned that it *has* to be inside `\[...\]`. That's why I was wondering if you could in any way use tags inside `\align` (or `\align*` or `\aligned`) within `\[...\]`, so hopefully it's not off-topic (I updated my question to more clearly reflect this). But I'll assume that I can't do it if even you aren't suggesting anything for it... ;)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Good night! Sleep tight. And thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry but he is wrong, it makes no sense to say you have to generate something that is a syntax error.

Comment: Well, he says that it parses it between the `\[...\]` because "it would not appear as math in non-TeX output formats (such as docx)." And something to do with the way pandoc doesn't know which format is going to be converted to with other format, so it can't make a specific exception when converting .tex into .pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}

Text text text.
% \[\begin{aligned}
% x &= 1 \tag{tag}\\
% \end{aligned}\]
Text text text.
\begin{align*}
    x&=1\tag{tag}\\
    y&=2\tag{tug}
\end{align*}
Text text text.

\end{document}
```

Note that you must *not* surround an `align` environment with `\[...\]`

Comment: @SkeletonBow if pandoc puts `align` inside `\[` then that is a pandoc bug and not really anything that can be done from the latex side.